# MongoDB aggregation: use $cond to check for a value in an array field

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection of users with an array-valued(!) state attribute.

I can easily find locked users

```
db.users.find({'state' : 'locked'})
```

because the condition "looks into" the state array.

However, I need this in the context of the aggregation framework and there I can't get it to work. Here's one of my non-working attempts:

```
db.users.aggregate({
  '$group' : {
    '_id' : { '$cond' : [{'$eq' : ['$state', 'locked']},
                      'locked',
                      'not_locked'] 
    },
    'count' : { '$sum' : 1 }
    }
})
```

IOW, I want to generate a group _id based on an elements presence in the state array.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want a document for each of the possible elements of state and count your original documents in each group for which they have a state...

You can do this by first doing an $unwind to split out the document/state combinations. Then group the states together.

If the states can be duplicated it might be a little trickier (unwind, group id/state, group state + count)

Answer (score 0):

there's an easy approach since v.3.2

```
...aggregate([
      {
        $addFields: {
          arrayFilter: {
            $filter: {
              input: '$someArray',
              as: 'item',
              cond: ['$$item', 'locked']
            }
          }
        }
      },
      {
        $unwind: '$arrayFilter'
      },
      {
        $project: {
          arrayFilter: 0
        }
      }
    ]);
```

1. Add a field filtered by 'locked'
2. $unwind on the resulting array (pipeline results with empty arrays get removed)
3. (optional) remove filter field from result via project